# Filter Dictionary keys of multilevel dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have the following `dict` structure:

```
{12345: {2006: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}]}, 12346: {2007: [{'a': 2, 'b': 7}, {'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 12}]}}
```

I want to be able to filter based on the keys of `'a'` or `'b'`

for example if `'a' is 1` the my filtered `dict` would look like:

```
{12345: {2006: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}]}, 12346: {2007: [{'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 12}]}}
```

I have the following for loop which gets me down to where I have the inner `dict's` I want, but I am not sure how to put it back into a `dict` of the same structure.

```
    d = {12345: {2006: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}]}, 12346: {2007: [{'a': 2, 'b': 7}, {'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 12}]}}

    d_filter = {}
    for item_code in d.keys():
        for year in d[item_code]:
            for item_dict in d[item_code][year]:
                if item_dict['a'] == 1:
                    print(item_dict)  # how to put this back in d_filter?
```

producing:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'b': 9}
{'a': 1, 'b': 12}
```

I am guessing there is a better way to filter that I can not find, or something with dictionary comprehension that my small mind can not grasp.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected result for `d_filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a *dictionary comprehension* that does just that; `dct` is your initial dictionary:

```
d = {k: {ky: [d for d in vl if d['a']==1] for ky, vl in v.items()} 
                                          for k, v in dct.items()}
print d
# {12345: {2006: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}]}, 12346: {2007: [{'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 12}]}}
```

You can change the inner filter (i.e. `d['a']==1`) to the dict key and/or value of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
filtered = {
     item_code: {
         year: [item for item in items if item['a'] == 1]
         for year, items in years.items()
     } 
     for item_code, years in d.items()
}
```

Which results in:

```
{12345: {2006: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}]},
 12346: {2007: [{'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 12}]}}
```

Comment: this works too, but i guess I can pick only one answer